# Adding to a loop in PHP without overwriting

Tags: php, mysql, performance, loops

I am trying to store the dates and month name from my database in this format. I am aiming to store the month and then count the entries in that month and then store the count. This is my loop, but I have trouble formatting the array properly.

```
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res) ) {
    if ($row['Date'] != $prev_date) {
        $values=array(
            $row['Date'] => $count,
        );

        $prev_date = $row['Date'];
    }

    $count++;
}
print_f($values);
```

You can see that I will always overwrite my previous array and I am not really adding entries into the array. I couldn't figure out how to do it. I'm basically trying to see the number of entries per month.

OLD Update: Currently learning the MYSQL thing that one commenter mentioned. I'll update when I get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *almost* got it!

```
$values=array();
    while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res) ) {
        if ($row['Date'] != $prev_date) {
            $values[$row['Date']] =  $count;

            $prev_date = $row['Date'];
            $count = 0;
        }

        $count++;

    }
```

**Update:** Need a little help with this part.

My output:

```
Array ( [9] => [10] => 999 [11] => 986 )
```

999 was supposed to be stored in 9 and 986 was supposed to be stored in 10.

**Update:** Here's my new code, I would appreciate it if someone can show me a more efficient way.

```
    $sql = "SELECT MONTH(AddDate) AS Date, column_name FROM table ORDER BY AddDate ASC";
    $res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    $prev_date = null;

$values=array();

    while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res) ) {
        if ( $row['Date'] != $prev_date) {
            $month = $row['Date'];
            $sql = "SELECT count(MONTH(AddDate)) AS EntryAmount FROM `table` WHERE MONTH(AddDate)=$month ";
            $countResults = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
            if( $entryAmount = mysql_fetch_array($countResults) ) {
                $values[$row['Date']] =  $entryAmount['EntryAmount'];
            }
            $prev_date = $row['Date'];
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
Array ( [9] => 999 [10] => 986 [11] => 264 )
```

Comment: @Mark Updated the original query

Answer (score 2):

You can make this using `group by` in sql, some like this: `select date, count(*) from table group by date`

Edit:
If you need only count by month use some like this: `select MONTH(dateField) as NewDate, count(*) FROM table GROUP BY NewDate`

Comment: If that's what you're trying to accomplish, it will be *much* more efficient to do it in the query than in PHP.

Comment: Okay, let me try this instead

Comment: I couldn't get this to work the way I want to. I don't know when does the date start in my database and I need to count the amount of entries for each month. I can only count it the amount of each month if I can define WHERE Month = 'x'. Maybe I am missing something.

Comment: Do you need a counter for a year/month or only for a month? Show me the SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand what you're trying to do.  How about this?

```
$values[$row['Date']]++;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about looping on the result of a query something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(MONTH(AddDate)) AS EntryAmount, MONTH(AddDate) as MonthValue FROM table GROUP BY MONTH(AddDate)
```